# Como obter só uma parte de uma string à partir de um padrão?

Tags: string, regex, lua

Tenho uma *string* em linguagem Lua. Quero obter só a parte do `filename` através do *match* (`403.htm.en`).

Exemplo:

```
var=[[Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="403.htm.en"
     Content-Type: text/plain; name='403.htm.en'
     Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
    ]]
filename = string.match(var,"filename(.+)")
print("filename", filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se a forma mais confiável mas isto funciona:

```
var = [[Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="403.htm.en"
     Content-Type: text/plain; name='403.htm.en'
     Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
    ]]
filename = string.match(var,"filename=\"(.+)\"")
print("filename = ", filename)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/l5aBvH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sqmpwbtc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/RegEx.lua).

Tinha que colocar os delimitadores de onde você que r que o texto comece e termine.